# How to display date and time in webpage continuously and update in MySQL database simultaneously?

Tags: php

I want to display time in the web page every second and update in the MySQL database simultaneously for my project. I tried it with PHP. But the page needs to be refreshed every second to do this. Making a server call every second dosen't seem like a good idea to me. Is there any other way to do this?

```
<?php
$url1=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
echo ("Date: $date");

$dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

mysqli_select_db($dbhandle, "testing") or die("Cannot select database");
$sql = "INSERT INTO data ".
       "(date)".
       "VALUES ( '$date')";
mysqli_query( $dbhandle,$sql );

header("Refresh: 1; URL=$url1");
?>
```

Comment: don't store dates as strings in the database. You'll regret it later. use native date/datetime types.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. But in my project that dosen't matter.

Comment: why do you need it?why this information is useful like say, 12:00:00,12:00:01,12:00:02,12:00:03,12:00:04..etc

Answer (score 0):

You can have an element on the page to both display the date/time and write to the database. Use an interval to trigger ajax calls:

```
<html>
<body>
<span id="mytime"></span>

<script src="http://www.antradar.com/download/nano.js"></script>
<script>
setInterval(function(){
  ajxpgn('mytime','updatetime.php?');
},1000); //update every second
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The updatetime.php code would be the same as yours, except that you want to omit the header part.

The ajxpgn function in the Nano Ajax library is similar to the ajax updater function in prototype.js and jQuery, except that if a second request is sent to server and the first request is still in flight for any reason, the [first request is canceled](http://www.antradar.com/blog-in-order-ajax-handling) to avoid congestion.